Android10 (API 29) Downloaded file with DownloadManager is queued, but never downloading
The method I tried works on Android 8.1. But it doesn't work on Android 10.There is probably a point in API 29 that I should pay attention to, but I'm not sure about it. I found out that there is no need for write permission to external storage in Android 10+.I can't find the problem.I changed setDestinationInExternalPublicDir, changed setMimeType and changed setAllowedNetworkTypes, but nothing worked.The file always remains queued.
var getUrl = downloadPath // http://10.40.61.174/AxionAPK/AXION.apk
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(getUrl))
val title = URLUtil.guessFileName(getUrl, null, null)
        request.setTitle(title)
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(false)
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(path))
        request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive")
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
//request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,title)
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),title)
//request.setDestinationUri(this@LogonActivity.filesDir.toUri())
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI )
//request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI )
val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request)```

